# how to check the number continure or not in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have database like:

```
id  |  lownumber | highnumber | content
---------------------------------------
1   |   10       |   13       | text
2   |    14      |    19      |  book
3   |    6       |     9      |  table
...
```

I want to check the lownumber and highnumber contine or not. I mean the previous highnumber + 1 equal the next line lownumber or not? how to do that in postgresql?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the exceptions using `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(highnumber) over (order by id) as prev_highnumber
      from t
     ) t
where lownumber <> prev_highnumber + 1;
```

Note:  "previous" is ambiguous.  I don't know from the question if it refers to the previous row based on `id` or `lownumber`.  If the latter, then change the `order by`.

Comment: Shouldn't you `ORDER BY` lownumber?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . To be honest, I don't know.  I interpreted "previous" as based on the id, but you may also be right in your interpretation.